# Wordpress custom post types category

Tags: wordpress, categories, custom-post-type

I'm building a wordpress website for a travel agent who offers special deals to various locations and displays them on one page.  So, I've used the following code to allow for  filtering of the custom post type that I setup, with individual post excerpts and images being displayed.

Here's what I have:

```
<code>
    <?php
/**
 * Template Name: Deals 1 column
 */

get_header(); ?>

<div id="content" class="two_third <?php echo of_get_option('blog_sidebar_pos') ?>">

<div id="sort">
        <h5>SORT BY : </h5>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="<?php echo add_query_arg(array ('paged' => '1',  'orderby' => 'date', 'order' => 'DESC'));?>">Date</a></li>
            <li><a href="<?php echo add_query_arg(array ('paged' => '1',  'orderby' => 'title', 'order' => 'ASC'));?>">Deal (A to Z)</a></li>
            <li><a href="<?php echo add_query_arg(array ('paged' => '1',  'orderby' => 'meta_value', 'order' => 'ASC', 'meta_key' => 'price'));?>">price (A to Z)</a></li>
        </ul>
</div>
<div id="filter">
        <h5>FILTER BY : </h5>
        <ul>
        <?php
        $categories=  get_categories('taxonomy=types&title_li=');
        foreach ($categories as $category){ ?>
        <li><a href="<?php echo add_query_arg(array ('paged' => '1',  'filter' => $category->category_nicename));?>" title="Filter by <?php echo $category->name;?>"><?php echo $category->name;?></a></li>
        <?php }?>
        </ul>
</div>
<div id="reset-filters">
        <a href="<?php echo add_query_arg(array ('paged' => '1',  'filter' => ''));?>">reset filters</a>
</div>



<div id="gallery" class="one_column">

    <ul class="portfolio">
        <?php
        $query = 'post_type=gs_deals&types='.$_GET['filter'].'&orderby='.$_GET['orderby'].'&order='.$_GET['order'].'&meta_key='.$_GET['meta_key'].'&posts_per_page=3&paged='.$paged;
        query_posts($query);
        if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();
        $custom = get_post_custom(get_the_ID()); 
        ?>
        <?php
        $categories=  get_categories('taxonomy=types&title_li=');
        foreach ($categories as $category){ ?>
        <div id="category"><h3><?php echo $category->name;?></h3>
        <?php }?>
        <li class="clearfix">
            <div class="clearfix">
                <span class="image-border"><a class="image-wrap" href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php _e('Permanent Link to', 'theme1512');?> <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" ><?php the_post_thumbnail( 'portfolio-post-thumbnail-xl' ); ?></a></span>
                <div class="folio-desc">
                <h6 class="project">Deal!</h6>
                <p><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php echo get_the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></p>
                <h6 class="client">Price :</h6>
                <h4><?php echo $custom["price"][0];?></h4>
                <p class="short"><?php echo $custom["short_text"][0];?></p>
                <p><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">View Details</a></p>
            </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        </div>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        <?php endif;?>

    </ul>
    <div class="posts-nav">
        <div class="prev"><?php next_posts_link(__('? Older Projects')) ?></div>
        <div class="next"><?php previous_posts_link(__('Newer Projects ?')) ?></div>
    </div>
</div><!-- #content -->
</div>
<!-- end #main -->
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>


</code>
```

And here's my functions.php that handles this:

```
//////REGISTER A CUSTOM POST TYPE
add_action('init', 'gs_deals_register');//Always use a shortname like "gs_" not to see any 404 errors

function gs_deals_register(){
    $args = array(
        'label' => __('Deals List'),
        'singular_label' => __('Deals'),
        'public' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'deals'),//Use a slug like "work" or "project" that shouldnt be same with your page name
        'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail')//Boxes will be showed in the panel
       );

    register_post_type( 'gs_deals' , $args );
}

//////ADD CUSTOM INPUTS (Client & Short_text)
add_action("admin_init", "admin_init");
add_action('save_post', 'save_options');

function admin_init(){
    add_meta_box("gs_dealsInfo-meta", "Deals Options", "meta_options", "gs_deals", "side", "low");
}

function meta_options(){
    global $post;
    $custom = get_post_custom($post->ID);
    $price = $custom["price"][0];
    $short_text = $custom["short_text"][0];
    ?>
    <p><label>Price:</label><br /><input name="price" value="<?php echo $price; ?>" /></p>
    <p><label>Short Text:</label><br /><textarea name="short_text"><?php echo $short_text; ?></textarea></p>
<?php
}

function save_options(){
    if ( defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) return $post_id;
    global $post;
    update_post_meta($post->ID, "price", $_POST["price"]);
    update_post_meta($post->ID, "short_text", $_POST["short_text"]);
}

//////ADD TAXONOMY FOR FILTERING (Taxonomy name: types)
register_taxonomy("types", array("gs_deals"), array("hierarchical" => true, "label" => "Types", "singular_label" => "Types", "rewrite" => true));

//////ADD HOOKS FOR PANEL VIEW
add_filter("manage_edit-gs_deals_columns", "gs_deals_edit_columns"); 
add_action("manage_posts_custom_column",  "gs_deals_custom_columns");

function gs_deals_edit_columns($columns){
    $columns = array(
        "cb" => "<input type=\"checkbox\" />",
        "title" => "Deal Title",
        "short_text" => "Short Text",
        "price" => "Price",
        "types" => "Types",
    );

    return $columns;
}

function gs_deals_custom_columns($column){
    global $post;
    $custom = get_post_custom();
    switch ($column)
    {
        case "short_text":
            echo $custom["short_text"][0];
            break;
        case "price":
            echo $custom["price"][0];
            break;
        case "types":
            echo get_the_term_list($post->ID, 'types', '', ', ','');
            break;
    } 
}
```

I'd like to display the category name above the corresponding posts, but it doesn't seem to be working out.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have categories enabled for your custom post type in functions.php?

```
 register_taxonomy_for_object_type('category', '[name of custom post type]');
```

Also, have you tried doing a var_dump() of the categories variable after calling the get_categories() function?

Comment: Here's my functions.php pertaining to this:

Comment: Actually, I can't seem to get my code to display in a comment.  Any advise?

Comment: For comments, you can use the grave key around the code `<?php echo("") ?>`, but it may be easier just to post the whole file in the original post.

Comment: Hey Dan, Thanks for the advice.  I added the function to the top post.